# How can I integrate FaceBook with XMPP?

Tags: javascript, xml, facebook, integration, xmpp

I want to integrate Facebook with xmpp and want to make a chat facility for my website,
please assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into using a javascript library to integrate with FaceBook XMPP.

---

One that I've used in the past is strophe.js

http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/

Strophe provides the following features:

- XMPP compliant (Strophe.js compatibility matrix libstrophe compatibility matrix)
- Browser and platform agnostic (Strophe.js)
- TLS support via SChannel, GNUTLS, or OpenSSL (libstrophe)
- SASL authentication using ANONYMOUS, DIGEST-MD5, or PLAIN methods as well as legacy jabber authentication
- Customizable logging and memory management

---

Information on how FaceBook wants you to use their XMPP service can be found here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

> You can integrate Facebook Chat into your Web-based, desktop, or mobile instant messaging products. Your instant messaging client connects to Facebook Chat via the Jabber/XMPP service. This document describes the features and limitations of Facebook Chat's XMPP protocol for the developer who intends to implement a Facebook Chat client.

Comment: thanks guys, but i do not know how do i compile a file of python on my server ?

Comment: python has nothing to do with it, strophe is all javascript. I've worked with XMPP and it is not simple, but it does work.